# How to pass return Uri as route parameter?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a list page with a list of widgets.  I want to go to a page to view one widget with a return URL so that we can get back to the list afterwards.

```
@page "widgetlist"

<a href=@($"widget/{@widget.Id}/{NavigationManager.Uri}")>@widget.Name</a>
```

My widget view page:

```
@page "widget/{widgetid}/{returnuri}"

You are viewing widget id: @WidgetId<br />
You were sent here by: @ReturnUrl

@code {
    [Parameter] public string WidgetId { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

When clicking the anchor on the list, this causes a not found when try to navigate to the widget page.  If I replace my anchor href as:

```
<a href=@($"widget/{widget.Id}/sometext")>@widget.Name</a>
```

then it routes correctly and I see that I was sent by "sometext".

So, I guess the problem is the fact that the second parameter includes the https:: and slashes, etc.

How can I address this?

Comment: Yeah, you presumably need to url encode (and then decode) the string. (`System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(NavigationManager.Uri)`)

Comment: Just the job!  Thanks.  Actually no need to decode.  Was able to just use the received route parameter in an anchor on the widget view page with no modifications.  Cheers!